# Theorem about bounded functions.

Tags: bounded-variation, piecewise-continuity

Is there a theorem that says that if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a piecewise function, then it is bounded?

Answer (score 2):

Not without more restrictions, like continuity (which is enough).

For example, consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,& x=a \\
\dfrac{1}{x-a},& a<x\leq b\\
\end{cases}
$$

If your function is continuous, then it is bounded since the continuous image of a compact set is compact (in $\mathbb{R}$, this means it is closed and bounded).

Comment: And if it has a finite number of discontinuous points?

Comment: Nothing more can be said without more restrictions. My example has exactly one discontinuity, yet it is unbounded.

Comment: That's what I meant. So, how can I prove that it is bounded? Should I consider piece by piece and find a bound? The pieces I have are a parabola, a horizontal ray and another ray.

Comment: "Continuous" only makes sense when applied to a function. It doesn't describe a "piece" of the domain. Perhaps you are thinking of "connected" ?

Comment: I told so because I thought you were telling me that your function was a continuous one.

Comment: Yes, if $f|_I$ is bounded for each of the intervals $I$ of the domain, and there are finitely many of them, then $f$ is bounded by the largest of these bounds.

Comment: My function is *not* continuous. It demonstrates that the answer to your question is "No" unless you add further restrictions. Also, it isn't even enough to require that $f$ is continuous on each of the pieces, because my function is continuous on each piece.

Comment: So if one piece is $x^2$ if $x\in [0,1]$ should I say that $x^2 $ assumes values in this interval and the same for the other two pieces?

Comment: Yes. If the pieces of the graph actually hook up, then $f$ is continuous so the function is bounded (because the image is compact, so bounded). If they don't hook up, then your domain intervals can't all be closed intervals since you must have a discontinuity. BUT--if each of the pieces extends to a continuous function on a closed interval, then each piece is bounded. Then the whole function is bounded (if there are finitely many pieces). The piece $(a,b]$ of my example can't be extended this way to $[a,b]$.

Comment: If the upper bounds on your pieces are $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_N$, then $\max_i B_i$ is an upper bound for $f$. Similarly for the lower bound, looking instead at the minimum of the lower bounds.

Comment: So, if I understood well, since I have a parabola and two rays in [0,5], I can conclude that my piecewise function, even if it has discontinuity, it is bounded. Is there a thereom that I can cite? Or should I say the bounds for each piece? And I have to say it for the lower bounds and the upper ones?

Comment: I doubt it, but it's certainly a theorem you can prove. I just about did so in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If the piecewise function has some isolated points, does it change?